# How to use striptags twig function in a commerce product template?

Tags: theming, commerce, 9

For a client I need a wysiwyg field on my nodes and commerce products so they can add `<em>` and `<span>&nbsp;</span>` tags in their titles.

I display this *title_nbsp* field value in the templates (full and teaser) using

- `{{ node.title_nbsp|striptags('<span><em>')|raw }}` for the nodes
- `{{ product.title_nbsp|striptags('<span><em>')|raw }}` for the products

I've got no problem with the nodes, but for the products it leads me to an error "*The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.*"

> TypeError : strip_tags(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in strip_tags() (/var/www/arvalis/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php ligne 1120)

I then tried to use `{{ product_entity.get('title_nbsp').value|striptags('<span><em>')|raw }}` and it works on the website for both `full` and `teaser` view modes ; no more error.

I was happy but... I also need to index a `teaser` render of those contents through the search API.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_search_api_algolia_objects_alter().
 */
function mymodule_search_api_algolia_objects_alter(array &$objects, IndexInterface $index, array $items) {
  foreach ($objects as &$object) {
    [$object_type, $object_params] = explode(':', $object['search_api_id']);
    if ('entity' === $object_type') {
      [$entity_type, $entity_id] = explode('/', $object_params);
      $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
      $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
      $entity = $storage->load($entity_id);
      $build = $view_builder->view($entity, 'teaser');
      $object['teaser'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($build);
    }
  }
}
```

Once again no problem for the nodes, but for the products... `drush sapi-i my_commerce_products_index` leads me to

> Unable to decode output into JSON: Syntax error
> TypeError: strip_tags(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given in strip_tags() (line 1120 of /var/www/arvalis/vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php).

Is there a way to use that `striptags` twig function so it could work everywhere for commerce products as it's the case for the nodes ?
Why is the `teaser` view mode generating an error when it is generated by a cli drush command ?

I am using Drupal 9.4.7 and Commerce Core 8.x-2.31

Comment: Try changing `renderPlain()` to `renderRoot()` and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I have the exact same error after this change + a cache rebuild

Comment: I ended up using a preprocess function to php `strip_tags` the value instead of doing it in the template... Still really weird that I met this error especially when the value printed with the twig dump() function is a string but from the cli it seems that it's an array ‍

Comment: The preprocess function is the correct place to do it. Processing should not be done in templates, they are purely for output.